# Inscribing equilateral triangles in convex curves

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

I'm interested in solving the following problem (Problem 12-5 of "Introduction to Analysis" by Arthur Mattuck). Although the problem reads "Show convincingly", I'm after a rigorous proof.

> Let $C$ be a smooth, convex, closed curve, i.e., one without endpoints, and such that a line segment joining any two points on $C$ lies inside $C$. (An ellipse or an oval are examples. "Smooth" means it has a tangent line at each point.)
>
> Let $P$ be any point on $C$. Show convincingly that you can always find two other points $Q$ and $R$ on $C$ such that $PQR$ is an equilateral triangle. (Try some sketches.)

**My attempt:**

Let us denote by $D$ the region inside of $C$, and let $\mathcal{T}_P$ denote the set of all equilateral triangles, one of the vertices of which being $P$. I considered then the set
$$S:=\{a \geqslant 0: \text{there exists a triangle $\Delta \in \mathcal{T}_P$ with side length $a$, contained entirely in $\overline{D}$}\}. $$
I tried showing that $S$ is a closed interval of the form $[0,d]$, and then showing that a maximal triangle of side length $d$ must be touching the curve at three points. However, I couldn't complete the argument.

I understand that being an introductory textbook, it is not expected from a reader to provide a rigorous proof here, but I'm curious to see what such a proof would like.

I would appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix point $P$. From $P$ let $Q$ traverse the curve in a clockwise direction (starting at $P$ and taking $PQ$ to be the tangent at $P$) and let $PR$ be a line at $60^{\circ}$ clockwise from $PQ$, with $R$ the point of intersection with the curve.

As $Q$ traverses the curve until $PR$ reaches its limit as the tangent at $P$ the triangles $PQR$ have a sixty degree angle at $P$. $PQ$ starts at length zero so that $PQ-PR$ is negative. $PR$ ends at zero so $PQ-PR$ is positive. Given (and to be rigorous you'd have to prove this) that $PQ-PR$ varies continuously, it must take a zero value.

Another fact you'd have to prove to be rigorous is that $R$ exists - if you had a corner at $P$ with angle less than sixty degrees, there would be no equilateral triangle (but there is no tangent at a corner, so you have to use the properties of the tangent).